# Export CentOS Ec2 Instance to Physical Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vmware, centos6, ec2-ami

Is there a way to export CentOS Ec2 Instance to physical machine ? I need to literally make the CentOS of the ec2 instance to be the OS of the machine, not running it locally on a VMWare or any other virtual machine tools.

The case I have is that I have a very complicated CentOS Ec2 Setup and we need to make it run offline in physical machine. I did some searches and find no useful information about whether I can do that or not.

If not possible to export directly, would it be possible to export the ec2 to VMWare, then create DVD installer from the VMWare instance, then use the DVD to install the CentOS instance in physical machine ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by following Amazon Ec2 import/export concept. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

1. created VMWare instance, imported to EC2
2. did the proper environment setup there
3. then exported as VMWare
4. compared the original imported VM with the exported one and created a diff files
5. a script of the diff was created to be installed at post-install of CentOS installation

Works like a charm!